# Is it possible to load part of the page before any Server-side transaction in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, progress-bar, client-side, server-side

I have a **Login** page which is redirected to Heavy "**Dashboard**" page and I want to show ***just part of "Dashboard" HTML page***(for exp the Menu and other Main HTMLs from MasterPage) ***before the rest of the page is loaded from server *** . thats because I want to show user,the "Progress Bar" at top of "Dashboard" Page.

My question is "*Is it possible to load part of the page before any Server-side transaction*?" How can I do that?
I couldnt even get close to the solution, as I dont know how to search and what should I search?

Or if any other solution comes into your mind I will be glad to know that.

Could anyone please give me any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to load the "visible part" of the page using 1 request and then load the remaining part of the page using another (AJAX) request. The workflow would go like:

1. The page would be loaded like normal. Only the markup that contains the part you want visible during loading should be in this page. It should also contain JavaScript to create an AJAX request back to the server that executes upon the page load. This JavaScript will typically be what shows the "loading" prompt (usually with an animated GIF). It helps to facilitate AJAX through a JavaScript framework such as JQuery or AngularJS.
2. In ASP.NET, you can respond to an AJAX request either by making a static method on the page or by creating an HTTP handler. You could simplify the process a little by using WebApi. This method is responsible for returning the remaining part of the page. This can be the result of a user control that is executed server side to produce an HTML string, markup that is generated manually, or you can just return a model as JSON and then use JavaScript to generate the HTML on the client.
3. Upon the second return trip from the server, the AJAX callback function is executed and it adds the necessary HTML to the DOM and then hides the "loading" prompt.

There are a lot of moving parts and it takes some work (and some searching) to put together, but it is doable.

Comment: I didnt catch first part. The markup I want to load before rest of the page is Master Page, and Panel for Ajax. did you mean I should Have two separate pages ?
Could you please provide me with some link for sample if you have?

Comment: NightOwl888: I want to use bootstrap progressbar instead of a GIF for loading, means some work in Serverside .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  The page is processed by the server and the full results are then sent to the client.  The client gets nothing until the server is done.  What you want to do is more advanced than this basic model allows.

Now there are options to do what you want.  It requires more advanced techniques than the basic, old school, web design used by most folks.  Start with AJAX, learning about it will show you new ways of doing things.

After that, have a look a jQuery.  This will simplify AJAX for you.  You need to know AJAX basics before you do this.

From there you should be able to piece out the rest of it.

A good learning site is http://www.w3schools.com (it has sections for both AJAX and jQuery)

Comment: I know how to use ajax and jQuery . Just dont know how can I call part of the page and loading remaining part? should I use Threading ?

Comment: @SarahN In that case, assuming you are using MS Visual Studio, the UpdatePanel control performs partial-page updates and identifies content that is updated independently of the rest of the page.  If you need an example of using it have a look at http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/CreateSimpleAJAXApplication.aspx

Comment: Also, as you want to use a progress bar of some kind, have a look at http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdateProgress.aspx